# Can laravel controllers functions be variables?

Tags: php, laravel

My question is simple, i want to create a variable route, but i want to create a variable function inside the route.

Is this posible?

```
Route::get('/{tabla}/get','WebSystem\{tabla}@{tabla}')->name('activities');
```

Comment: I did not understand what you want to achieve

Comment: @GiacomoM I want to create a route where the controller and function  are variable

Comment: No, the target string is always interpreted as a string. It cannot be defined dynamically.

Comment: You could possibly do it inside a controller, but I'm not sure I'd recommend it. It can potentially be a big can of worms, best keep that lid closed.

Comment: You could use a callback function as the target and resolve the controller manually, but I would strongly advice against it. This would possibly skip middlewares and prevent caching for example.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea, in case of method not found you will get a MethodNotFoundException unless you write the __call(); why don't you specify a method to call then do the logic from there instead?, it should act the same but it's better to manage, having a call lets say: CallMethodsController@call, and from there you can do whatever you want, cleaner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use different notation (it require to change default namespace in your routeServiceProvider):

```
Route::get('/{tabla}/get, [ExampleController::class, 'methodName'])->name('activities');
```

Which leads us to:

```
$controller = ExampleController::class;
$methodName = 'methodName';
Route::get('/{tabla}/get', [$controller, $methodName]);
```

In addition, this approach guarantee that some IDE (like PhpStorm) will refactor your routes. In example: when you want to change name or namespace of your controller.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can.

web.php

```php
   $func_name = 'testFunction';
   Route::get('test', "Controller@{$func_name}");
```

controller.php

```php
    public function testFunction()
    {
        echo 'yes working';
        die;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method

```
Route::get('/{tabla}/get, [Controller::class,'method'])->name('activities');
```

Answer (score 0):

See the below one, this could work,

```
Route::get('/one/{class}/{method}', function(Request $request, $class, $method) use ($router) {
    $n = "App\Http\Controllers\ $class";
    $n = explode(' ', $n);
    $n = implode('', $n);
    $n = new $n;

    return $n->{$method}($request);
});
```